# How can I retain NA's in timestamp when using dapply

Tags: sparkr

I'm trying to convert many date characters columns to timestamp format using dapply. However rows that are empty characters are being converted to the origin date "1970-01-01".

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("12/31/2016", "12/31/2016", "12/31/2016"), 
             b = c("01/01/2016", "01/01/2017", ""))

ddf <- as.DataFrame(df)

schema <- structType(
    structField("a", 'timestamp'),
    structField("b", 'timestamp'))

converted_dates <- dapply(ddf, 
            function(x){ as.data.frame(lapply(x, function(y) as.POSIXct(y, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))) },
            schema)

 head(converted_dates)
       a          b
1 2016-12-31 2016-01-01
2 2016-12-31 2017-01-01
3 2016-12-31 1970-01-01
```

whereas running the function within the dapply call on an R data.frame retains the NA result for the empty date value

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(y) as.POSIXct(y, format = "%m/%d/%Y")))
       a          b
1 2016-12-31 2016-01-01
2 2016-12-31 2017-01-01
3 2016-12-31       <NA>
```

Using Spark 2.0.1